# ngrok with visual studio 2017 and IIS express fails to connect

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, twilio, iis-express, ngrok

So I'm trying to setup my dev machine to be able to respond to some webhooks, as per the twilio documentation here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/tutorials/how-use-ngrok-windows-and-visual-studio-test-webhooks

I've got ngrok installed, and have the tunnel up and running, pointing at the port that is specified in visual studio. In this case, 44336.
[image]
[image]

However, if I go to visit the external URL, I get a very long load time, and eventually a 502 error. Visiting localhost works fine as expected.

So, I tried setting ngrok to point at 8080, and I get a little further along, but still no luck with the following error message in the browser.

[image]

With the first tunnel attempt, I can see the GET/ requests show up in the ngrok client, but no error. In the second attempt, I can see the 502 errors:

[image]

So I have two questions: How can I diagnose the source of the problem? And how can I setup IIS to accept connections from ngrok?

Comment: Note: I've tried bind-tls=true and bind-tls=both, due to my app using HTTPS.

Comment: So I just tried to go pure TLS, and I got a new error.

So the new command looks like:
ngrok tls -subdomain=xxxxxxxx 44336 

And I get an 'invalid hostname' 400 error

Comment: I'm not a Windows user, but there is also this blog post that might help you sort out these issues: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/03/configure-windows-for-local-webhook-testing-using-ngrok.html

Comment: Are you working with a .NET Core application?

Comment: Have you tried using the Visual Studio extension? It's supposed to get all the ngrok command line flags correct: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidProthero.NgrokExtensions -- Another thing I've seen is that if you are on a company-managed laptop, they've locked it down to prevent the type of tunneling that ngrok does.

Comment: I did try the visual studio extension, and no, I'm not using .Net Core.

I ended up installing a local version of IIS, and pushing my build to that. The best I can work out is that IIS express is sandboxed in some way that makes forwarding traffic difficult.

Comment: @philnash - I did come across that blog, but nothing from it seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Same issue with an ASP.NET Core project - all I would add is that I tried both IIS Express and Kestrel from VS 2017, tried all of the recommendations I can find, and I get 502 errors every time, although ngrok registers the requests.  Unfortunately HTTPS is required for my scenario.

Comment: @coryseaman - I did end up installing a local copy of IIS to my dev machine. You can set visual studio to use IIS.

Further, if you set Ngrok to http, it will do the HTTPS handshake and decode the traffic automatically.

Answer (score 23):

This is resolved in the latest version of ngrok (at this time 2.3.23).

A related closed issue can be referenced here: https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/issues/448

You can now run:

```
ngrok http https://localhost:<port> -host-header="localhost:<port>"
```

for your example:

```
ngrok http https://localhost:44336 -host-header="localhost:44336"
```

Answer (score -2):

Just go **Right click** on project -> **Properties**, and then **disable ssl**.

Comment: Um, nope can't do that. The user needs to be able to negotiate a single sign on auth pipeline.